# Is there any way to get the url which is part of IFrame tag in email or any other client

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have a requirement in which I have to send the dashboard in email. The Dashboard is in jsf and one jsf page url I am placing in IFrame tag and sending in email. But IFrame tag is not working in email. I googled it and found so many email clients won't support IFrame.

Is there any other way to complete this?

Comment: JSF is server side and totally unaware of iframes. So this is not jsf, nor jsp, not java-se related...!!!

Comment: It's all about to send the url which contains the dashboard, in an email. I tried it's working normally. but it's not working in email.

I googled it and found lot many email client wont support IFrame tag due to security reasons. 

FYI. https://www.simplycast.com/interactive-marketing-support/faqs/are-iframes-compatible-with-emails/

Comment: Could you please update on this?